# How to set the properties in a RecyclerView to update when the ViewModel List items properties are updated?

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-livedata

I've set up my project in such a way that the RecyclerView loads a list of Items from the ViewModel and then displays them. So the ViewModel stores a LiveData> which the RecyclerView observes and is supposed to update when it changes.

This works for cases if I want to delete or add an element in the list, but what if I want to update the text property of a list element? Since this isn't considered as modifying the list, the Observer is not triggered.

Essentially is there a way to work around this. I was thinking maybe it's possible to trigger the Observer manually from the ViewModel whenever a change occurs, but that sortof seems counter-intuitive to the whole principle of a ViewModel.

Some basic context code

MainFragment.kt:

```
mViewModel.allItems.observe(activity!!, Observer { newData ->
    adapter.data = newData
})
```

MainAdapter.kt:

```
var data = listOf<Item>()
    set(value) {
        field = value
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

MyViewModel.kt:

```
private val _allItems = MutableLiveData<List<Item>>()
    val allItems: LiveData<List<Item>>
        get() = _allItems
```

I would like the RecyclerView to be updated when I ran this in the ViewModel:

```
fun updateItem(arg : String) {
    for (item in _allItems.value!!) {
        if (item.text == arg) {
            item.text = "$arg: clicked!"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try just resetting the value of LiveData? `_allItems.postValue(_allItems.value)` after updating the item inside the list

Comment: That did it! I was looking for a function that did just that. I must've missed it in the documentation.

Comment: That's great, will post as answer. Would appreciate it if you accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try resetting the value of LiveData:

```
_allItems.postValue(_allItems.value)
```

after updating the item inside the list